# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Tags: php, function, constants

I have the following code

```
define("SCRIPT_URL", "");
function ifScriptFolder() {
    if(isset(SCRIPT_URL) && !empty(SCRIPT_URL)) {
        echo "/".SCRIPT_URL."/";
    } else {
        echo "/";
    }
}
```

but it's giving me the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in *(path)* on line 3
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong here or how to fix it?

Comment: I post an answer to show how to judge a constant is empty. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you trying to determine if constant exists, then try to use [`defined()`](http://php.net/defined) or [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant), not [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).

---

**From [php.net](http://php.net):**

*Function* [`defined()`](http://php.net/defined):

> Returns TRUE if the named constant given by name has been defined, FALSE otherwise.

*Function* [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant):

> Returns the value of the constant, or NULL if the constant is not defined.

---

Fixed function:

```
function ifScriptFolder() {
    echo defined('SCRIPT_URL') ? "/" . constant('SCRIPT_URL') . "/" : "/"
}
```

**UPD:**

The `defined()` function is a better solution for this, because it will not emit `E_WARNING` if constant was not defined.

Comment: Agreed that the functions should be used. However, the question is about a parse or compilation error i.e. the script does not even run so how can these functions be of help?

Comment: @fuzzybee This question about misuse and misunderstanig of use `isset()` for constant. And as the result - parse error.

Answer (score 5):

PHP [constants](http://php.net/define) are not variables, so you don't use `isset` or `empty` to check them.

Instead, you can use [`defined`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php):

```
defined('SCRIPT_URL')
```

to return a boolean if the field as been defined, then if it is, do a standard comparison on the value to check if it is truthy.

It's also worth noting (for future reference) that [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) is not a regular function; it is a "language construct" and cannot be used on anything besides variables (i.e. can't be used on the return value of a function).  Same with [`empty`](http://php.net/empty) up until PHP 5.5.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Never had to check a defined constant before. :). Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see if a variable exists, use `isset()`, and `defined()` only applies to constants.

If you want to check if a constant is empty, you can not use:

```
if (empty(B)) // syntax error
if (empty(constant('B'))) // fatal error
```

You can convert the constant to boolean:

```
if((boolean) A) {
}
```

So, you can change your code to:

```
<?php
define("SCRIPT_URL", "");
function ifScriptFolder() {
    if(defined('SCRIPT_URL') && !((boolean)SCRIPT_URL)) {
        echo "/".SCRIPT_URL."/";
    } else {
        echo "/";
    }
}
```

Comment: `defined()` requires string argument: `defined('SCRIPT_URL')`, not `defined(SCRIPT_URL)`.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I uptated the answer, tks.